# Error when mixing javascript and typescript in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use typescript in part of my angular application.
I have a ts file describing a class User:

```
module App.Tools {
    export class User {
        name: string;
        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my JS file (es2015) I try to import the class User:

```
import  {User} from 'User.ts';

export default class AuthFactory {
    /**
     * @param  {[type]}
     * @return {[type]}
     */
    constructor($firebaseAuth) {
        this.ref = new Firebase("...");

        // create an instance of the authentication service
        this.auth = $firebaseAuth(this.ref);

        var authData = this.auth.$getAuth();

        if (authData) {
            this.currentUser = new User(authData.google.displayName, authData.provider);
        } else {
            this.currentUser = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work as I get an error : "User is not defined".

I am using gulp with browserify, tsify and babel.

Comment: `.ts` extension does not belong to `import` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an "[external](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-going-external)" typescript module in "User.ts" file:

```
class User {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

export = User;
```

#### Update 1

Using internal modules:

```
module App.Tools {
    export class User {
        name: string;
        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}

export = App.Tools;
```

To use this in import:

```
import { User } from 'User.ts';
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately your solution is not working. THe line 'this.currentUser = new User(authData.google.displayName, authData.provider);' doesn't seem to work

Comment: Update: I've found that with nodejs it is not possible to use internal modules. Must stick with external modules.